# Liquibase: Copy value from one column to another that has array data-type

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, liquibase

I am using PostgreSQL with LiquibaseScript.

I am trying to change data type of a column from BIGINT to BIGINT[]. As underlying db doesn't allow the change, I am creating a new column with type BIGINT[] and dropping int one.
I need to copy the existing data from old column to new column from row to row.
I tried the below change

```
`<addColumn tableName="table1">
     <!-- <column name="new_column" type="BIGINT[]" value="ARRAY[old_column]"></column> -->
     <column name="new_column" type="BIGINT[]" value="(select ARRAY[old_column] from table1)"></column>
 </addColumn>`
```

The first option didn't throw any error but didn't work.
The second option didn't work because it expects where condition, and I don't know how to pass identity that belongs to the same row for all the rows.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: <sql>UPDATE promotion SET new_column=ARRAY[old_column]</sql> 
This one is working but checking for any alternative than native query.

Comment: untrue: postgresql does allow it 
`ALTER TABLE promotion ALTER COLUMN bar TYPE bigint[] USING array[ bar ];`

Comment: I found my mistake, as I was trying <modifyDataType> with newDataType as BIGINT[].
thanks, it changed the data type and renamed the column, but it didn't copy the original data. Did I miss anything?

Comment: it should have copies the exisitng data converted to single-element arrays.

Answer (score 2):

`addColumn` takes `valueComputed` attribute which allows you to duplicate values between two columns of tables.

> `valueComputed`
> The value that is returned from a function or
> procedure call. This attribute will contain the function to call.

You may want to try it this way:

```
<changeSet  id="1"  author="authorName">
    <addColumn tableName="table1">
        <column name="new_column" type="BIGINT[]" valueComputed="old_column"/>
    </addColumn>
  </changeSet>
```

I haven't tried with `BIGINT[]` type, but it works with `varchar` for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to split shared changeset onto 3:

1. Create new column with no value (and also add all needed constraints / index / foreign keys / etc)
2. Copy data from old column to new column
3. Drop old column

Having such separation allow easier rollback of each operation - and also have ddl and dml operations separated

Comment: I am doing the same, looking more specific for Liquibase script change.

Comment: <sql>UPDATE promotion SET new_column=ARRAY[old_column]</sql>
This one is working but checking for any alternative than native query.